# mailx command in Linux

Tags: linux, mailx

The below code is working fine in a Unix server for sending mail along with attachments from an array variable, i.e DISCARDED_FILE_NAME, but the same code is not working in Linux server, since `-m` in mail command is not supported in Linux; instead of it we need to use `-a`. I have tried with it as shown below, but it is still not working.

This code is working fine in a Unix server without any issue:

```
set -A DISCARDED_FILES $2
DISCARDED_FILE_NAME="DISCARDED"
echo "MRP_NAME" ${MRP_NAME}
RECEIVER="xyz@gmail.com"
echo "RECEIVER" ${RECEIVER}
SUBJECT="Error on ${MRP_NAME}"
BODY="Errore nell' elaborazione dell' ${MRP_NAME} Controllare file ${DISCARDED_FILE_NAME}"
echo "${BODY}"
(echo "$BODY\n";
for file in ${DISCARDED_FILES[@]}
do
uuencode $file `echo $file | cut -d'/' -f9`
done ) | mailx -m -s "${SUBJECT}" ${RECEIVER} 
echo mail sent
```

I modified accordingly to work in a Linux server but failed as shown below :

This code is not working in a Linux server:

```
MRP_NAME=$1
set -A DISCARDED_FILES $2
DISCARDED_FILE_NAME="DISCARDED"
echo "MRP_NAME" ${MRP_NAME}
RECEIVER="xyz@gmail.com"
echo "RECEIVER" ${RECEIVER}
SUBJECT="Error on ${MRP_NAME}"
BODY="Errore nell' elaborazione dell' ${MRP_NAME} Controllare file ${DISCARDED_FILE_NAME}"
echo "${BODY}"
(echo "$BODY\n";
for file in ${DISCARDED_FILES[@]}
do
uuencode $file `echo $file | cut -d'/' -f9`
DISCARDED_FILES+=( "-a"  $file)  
done ) | mailx "${DISCARDED_FILES[@]}" -s "${SUBJECT}" ${RECEIVER} 
echo mail sent
```

When I ran the above code in Linux server I got the below text in mail (body) without any attachments.

```
Errore nell' elaborazione dell'  Controllare file DISCARDED\n
begin 660 shell.txt
3=F%R=6X@:70@:7,@:6X@8F]D>0
end
begin 660 MoneticalBatchExtlogs.txt
M9&-T97)I;#`Q.B]A<'`O<W!E+TUO;F5T:6-A0F%T8VA%>'0O;&]G+T)312,@
M<V@@36]N971I8V%?3&]A9%]$871A7TU24#`Q+G-H"DU24%].04U%.B`M+2TM
M/B!-4E`P,0I-4E!?0TQ!4U-?3D%-13H@+2TM+3X@:70N<V5L;&$N;6]N971I
M8V%B871C:&5X="YA<'`N35)0,#%!<'`*0U123%]&24Q%3D%-13H@+2TM+3X@
M36]N971I8V%?3&]A9%]$871A7TU24#`Q+F-T;`I,3T=?1DE,13H@+2TM+3X@
M+V%P<"]S<&4O36]N971I8V%"871C:$5X="]L;V<O36]N971I8V%?3&]A9%]$
M871A7TU24#`Q7S$Q,#DR,#(P7S$U,#<Q-RYL;V<*6S$U.C`W.C$W72!-;VYE
M=&EC84)A=&-H17AT($U24#`Q('-C<FEP="!S=&%R="XN+@I;,34Z,#<Z,3==
M($UO;F5T:6-A0F%T8VA%>'0@35)0,#$@<V-R:7!T('-T87)T+BXN"ELQ-3HP
M-SHQ-UT@4W1A<G0@9V5N97)A=&EN9R!S97%U96YC92!F;W(@97AC97!T:6]N
M("XN+@I"051#2%]315%514Y#15])1"`](#(Q.#`X"ELQ-3HP-SHQ-UT@16YD
M(&=E;F5R871I;F<@<V5Q=65N8V4@9F]R(&5X8V5P=&EO;B`N+BX*6S$U.C`W
M.C$W72!3=&%R="!I;G-E<G1I;F<@8F%T8V@@9&5T86EL<RXN+@I;,34Z,#<Z
```

Comment: Please be specific: which "unix server" (Solaris, AIX, something else?) and which Linux distribution? Different versions of Unix & Linux use different versions of `mailx`, and the meaning of the options will vary. Some versions of `mailx` will accept attachments with the `-a` option, but e.g. for Debian 10's version, `-a` is the option to add extra header fields to the mail message.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `uuencode` and the resulting message body is correct, but can be decoded only by a mail agent that still understands a uuencoded attachment body.

Technically, [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uuencode.html) doesn't say that `uuencode` is obsolete but in practical terms MIME replaced `uuencode` years ago. You can use [`mpack`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mpack) to add one or attachments to an email message in a modern MIME-compliant way.

Your first included text file decodes just fine, by the way:

```
uudecode -o - </tmp/610367.txt ; echo
varun it is in body
```

The second one may be ignored because the `uuencode` specification doesn't say anything about handling multiple files per message, and some clients only expect one. (On the other hand you might be lucky. Better to use MIME though if you can.)